# How to enable Anti-Aliasing using DrawUserPrimitive on MonoGame

Tags: xna, monogame, antialiasing

How to enable the Anti-Aliasing using MonoGame to `DrawUserPrimitives`?

I've saw this other question: [Drawing Bezier curves in MonoGame (XNA) produces scratchy lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33977226/drawing-bezier-curves-in-monogame-xna-produces-scratchy-lines)

But the code isn't enabling the Anti-Alias.

I've setup a sample application here: https://github.com/viniciusjarina/PrimitiveDraw/blob/master/Game1.cs#L95

Even using `graphics.PreferMultiSampling = true;`

This is the output:

[image]

Comment: Just a note. Your exact code changing the OpenGL MG DLL for the DirectX MG DLL makes the antialiasing work. Whatever the problem is it's affecting MG OpenGL version only.

Comment: @KakCATI need to use DesktopGL since the idea is to do a Windows/Mac version even on Mac + OpenGL is still not smooth. I will try the DX MG later. Thank you.

Comment: I supposed you were using GL for that reason :) I just wanted to make that note because for developers it's important to specify the version the problem appears on. Both GL and DX should give the same results, but they're not there yet. My bet is it's a bug on GL's side or just unimplemented.

Comment: I found this issue: https://github.com/MonoGame/MonoGame/issues/6199 , however there's no "official answer" about that being a bug or unimplemented.

Answer (score -2):

Edited: This answer only covers how to make the code in the linked question actually work. I couldn't enable AA.

You'll need to set the culling to clockwise.

```
        GraphicsDevice.RasterizerState = new RasterizerState
        {
            CullMode = CullMode.CullClockwiseFace
        };
```

If that messes up your other primitives, you can simply reverse the order of the paths from

```
            path.Add(new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(curvePoints[x] + normal * curveWidth, 0), Color.Firebrick));
            path.Add(new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(curvePoints[x] + normal * -curveWidth, 0), Color.Firebrick));
```

to

```
            path.Add(new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(curvePoints[x] + normal * -curveWidth, 0), Color.Firebrick));
            path.Add(new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(curvePoints[x] + normal * curveWidth, 0), Color.Firebrick));
```

I'm using `VertexPositionColor` because I want a different color.

Comment: Still not working, try to enable the anti-aliasing in this application https://github.com/viniciusjarina/PrimitiveDraw

Comment: The code is working :)  and is drawing a line, but it looks like an Atari game

Comment: Yeah... a real shame I can't get AA to work. I must now reconsider how I will  work in Monogame moving forward.